# It's possible to execute machine code from file?

Tags: c++, c++11, assembly, c++14

I know that the inline asm exists, but is it also possible to execute machine code from a file during RUNTIME?

Would i need to write my own interpreter?

I'm using the GNU C++ compiler with c++ 14 enabled, on Windows 7.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you want your program to read its own assembly code? If not, then it's just a normal "read from a file" operation.

Comment: Possible? Package it as a dynamically loaded library.

Comment: _"I know that C++ compiles into a asm code..."_  compilers can be requested to produce assembly as intermediate output.  But I don't know of any modern compiler that compiles to human readable assembly code, instead they compile directly to machine code.

Comment: well compiler read nicely asm from files, thus you can invoke a compiler at runtime and try some dlopen opn what you've just compiled (obviously, remains a lot of work there, but you did not provided anything as well)

Comment: Wasn't it explicit enough? What i want is to read (literally, like the asm keyword) copmpiled asm code (or machine code) during runtime (while the program is running) just like a normal 'read from a file'.

Comment: No it's not explicit enough. It's still not clear to me what you want to do. If you want to read compiled code "like a read from a file", then did you try that and if so why did that not work for you?

Comment: Please differentiate `read` from `execute`.
Can you read? Yes you can, it's just binary data.
Can you execute? Yes, you can, but not trivially.
Is it easy to execute code you just randomly read from a file? Hell No...

Comment: @RichardCritten for example, `gcc` does. Not sure if that qualifies as "modern" :)

Comment: You will not necessarily need to write an interpreter, you could use a 3rd party one...
Would you please better describe the problem you're trying to solve via this method?

Comment: Also, please specify your environment? Unix/Linux/Windows/Other?

Comment: I'm using windows 7.

Comment: It is possible, it's called shellcode but writing a portable shellcode is going to be very sophisticated task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your rephrasing into machine code, this question starts taking a more reasonable shape.

A short answer: Yes, you can run machine code from within your application.
A longer answer is - it's complicated.

Essentially, any string of bits and bytes in memory can be executed, given some conditions are met, such as the data being legal machine instructions (Otherwise the processor will invoke the illegal instruction exception and the OS will terminate your program) and that the memory page into which the data is loaded is marked with executable permissions.

Having said that, the conditions required for that machine code to actually run correctly and do what you expect it to do, is significantly harder, and have to do with understanding of Virtual Memory, Dynamic Loaders and Dynamic Linkers.

To bluntly answer your question, for a POSIX compliant environment at the least, you could always use the `mmap` system call to map a file into memory with `PROT_EXEC` permissions and jump into that memory space hoping for the best.
Naturally, any symbols that code would be expecting to find in memory aren't likely to be there, and the code was better compiled as PIC (Position Independent Code) but this roughly answers your question with a YES.

For better control, you'd usually prefer to use a more standard method, such as compiling your extra code as a shared object (Dynamic Link Library, DLL in Windows) and loading it into your application with `dlopen` while using `dlsym` to access symbols within it. It still allows you to load machine code from the disk into your application, but it also stores the machine code in a well formatted, standard way, which allows the dynamic linker to properly load and link the new code segment into your application, reducing unexpected behavior.

In neither of these cases will you need an interpreter, but neither is it a matter of language or compiler used - this is OS specific functionality, and will behave quite differently on Windows.

As a different approach, you could consider using the `#include` directive to import an external chunk of assembly code into your work while you're still working on it and properly incorporate it in compile time, which will yield far more deterministic results.

Edit:
For windows, the parallel for `mmap` is [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx)
`dlopen` is [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)

Not a Windows expert, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Let us distinguish between "assembler code"/assembly code (which is what this question initially asked about) and machine code (after one of the edits).

Anything you might describe as "assembler code" (or more usually "assembly code") but not machine code (i.e. anything not being actual, binary, executable, machine code) cannot be "executed". You can only read it into what I would call an "assembly-code-interpreter" and have it processed. I do not know of any such a program. 
Alternatively, you can have it processed at runtime by a build process and execute the resulting executable. That however seems not to be what you are asking about.

Note that this does not mean that you can execute any machine code you might find in a file on your disk. It needs to be for the right, same platform and be supported by the appropriate runtime environment. That is applicable to executeables created for your machine or compatibles, e.g. the result of a built.

Note that I understand "assembler code" ("assembly code") to mean source code in assembly language, which is a (probably the most basic) representation of programs in (not really) human eye readable form. (As immortal has commented, an assembler is the program to process assembly code into machine code.) Opcode mnemonics are used, e.g. `cmp r1, r2` for comparing two registers. That string of characters however is guaranteed not to make any sense when trying to execute it straight forward. (OK, strictly speaking I should say "almost guaranteed"...)

Machine code which is appropriatly made for your environment, including a loader, can be executed from a file. Any operating system will support you doing that, most will even provide a GUI for doing that. (I notice this sounds somewhat cynical, sorry, not meant to be.) Windows for example will execute an executable if you double-click its icon in the windows explorer.

An alternative to such executable programs are libraries. Especially the dynamic link libraries are probably quite close to what you are thinking of. They are very similar, in needing to be targeted at your environment. Then they can  (usually partially) be executed from a linked program, via agreed calling mechanisms. Those mechanisms in turn ensure that the code is executed in a matching environment, including being able to return results.

Comment: Just some terminology: "Assembler" is the program that translates "Assembly" into machine code :)

Comment: Thanks, that was bothering me while typing, but I could not put my finger on it. Did incorporate. @immortal